# R: Reading data file with 201K records in R language

Tags: r, excel, large-files

I received an Excel datafile with slightly more than 201,000 records and 36 columns. What would be the best way to read the data into R.  Should I leave it as an xlsx file?  Should I dump it into a CSV file? Should I susbet the file into smaller files (rows of 10K each) and read them in separately?

So far, I have tried creating a 10,000 record subset and reading it using read.xls.  It only read in 2534 rows. It didn't give me an error, it just did not read all 10,000 rows.

I am running R on Windows 7 Ultimate with 8GB RAM.

Thank you in advance for any advice you can offer.

Comment: if it is one sheet, convert it to a csv and do read.csv. Your machine should handle it with no problems.

Comment: If speed is the matter, `fread()` in the `data.table` package is probably the one for you.

Comment: Definitely do not leave it as an xlsx. Follow the advice above.

Comment: as asked recently on SO, not reading certain lines may have to do with stray and/or unmatched quotation marks in the file -- try `quote=""` ...

Comment: I had a similar task. I exported the data to csv and then used `read.csv()` (or `read.csv2()` respectively). If you need to export the data back to xlsx later, you could go with [XLConnect](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/index.html). If you use that package in Windows, the line `options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1024m")` somewhere in the beginning of your script might help.